# Crossbrowser Alignment of menu to the bottom of header

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, alignment

I'm trying to realize a navigation menu like below. There should be no space between the black/red button and the border-bottom attribute of header. Especially the Safari browser makes some trouble. There is a big gap between the border and the navi item.

Here is a snippet of my HTML and CSS:

```css
*, *:before, *:after { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }

a:link, a:visited { color:#7C7C7C; text-decoration:none; }
header { border-bottom:1px solid #000000; }
.wrapper { margin:0 auto; }
.menu { list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; }
#header-nav { margin-top:3.5rem; }
#menu-main > li { float:left; }
#menu-main > li a { padding:0.2rem 0.8rem; line-height:1.71rem; height:1.71rem; }
#menu-main > li:hover a,
#menu-main > li.active a { color: #ffffff; background-color:#000000; }
#menu-main li:last-child { float:right; }
#menu-main li:last-child a { color:#ffffff; background-color:#ef2318; }
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="wrapper">
     <nav id="header-nav">
      <ul id="menu-main" class="menu clearfix">
       <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">How To</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Misc</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Basket</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Special Button</a></li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: you don't want space between buttons "Basket" and "Special Button" or between "Home" and "How To" ?

Comment: No!
I don't want space between the buttons and the border-bottom.

Comment: Your display:table is messing up with the browser.

Comment: Is there a better way to define the clearfix class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because the padding value is rendered differently in different browsers. 
Currently this line in your css is having the problem with the padding.

```
#menu-main > li a 
 {
    padding:0.2rem 0.8rem;
    line-height:1.71rem;
    height:1.71rem;
 }
```

One way to solve this issue is to use **box-sizing** css property in the element in which padding is used.
But in your code it is already used.

Other way is to use **display:block**, here's how you can use it:

```
#menu-main > li a
 {
    display:block;
    padding:0rem 0.8rem;
    line-height:1.71rem;
    height:1.71rem;
 }
```

Please note in this case you don't need the padding for top or bottom, so make it 0.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8rxaa83/1/).

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! Thank you.
I also removed height and line-height and let the padding as it was (0.2rem 0.8rem). With the height and line-height attributes the text wasn't aligned in the middle vertically.

Can you explain please, why display:block; helped here?

Comment: Display:block makes the contents of a tag display like a box. By default it is inline. So, it makes the text of the link use only the required area within the container, and so we need to use the padding stuff. But display as block makes it use the complete area spanning its container or parent. You can read here: http://htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/display/   or here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly : I just make line-height smaller :

1.71 -> 1.4 for  `#menu-main > li a`

```css
*, *:before, *:after { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }

a:link, a:visited { color:#7C7C7C; text-decoration:none; }
header { border-bottom:1px solid #000000; }
.wrapper { margin:0 auto; }
.menu { list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; }
#header-nav { margin-top:3.5rem; }
#menu-main > li { float:left;padding-top:0;}
#menu-main > li a { padding:0.2rem 0.8rem; line-height:1.4rem; height:1.71rem; }
#menu-main > li:hover a,
#menu-main > li.active a { color: #ffffff; background-color:#000000; }
#menu-main li:last-child { float:right; }
#menu-main li:last-child a { color:#ffffff; background-color:#ef2318; }
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="wrapper">
         <nav id="header-nav">
          <ul id="menu-main" class="menu clearfix">
           <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">How To</a>
</li>
           <li class="active"><a href="#">Shop</a>
</li>
           <li><a href="#">Misc</a>
</li>
           <li><a href="#">Basket</a>
</li>
           <li><a href="#">Special Button</a>
</li>
          </ul>
         </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```